# How to make glog output not fill 0 before number?

Tags: c++, glog

When I use glog to print an Eigen matrix in console, I found the output format has difference when using std::cout against using LOG(INFO). Here is the source code, in which 'sophus_R' is a 3x3 matrix.

```
LOG(INFO) << "using glog, sophus_R is:\n" << sophus_R.matrix();
std::cout << "using std::cout, sophus_R is:\n" << sophus_R.matrix() << std::endl;
```

And here is the output:

```
I0606 16:07:06.307516 122123 so3_test.cc:30] using glog, sophus_R is:
00000.696364 000-0.707107 00000.122788
00000.696364 00000.707107 00000.122788
000-0.173648 -2.08167e-17 00000.984808
using std::cout, sophus_R is:
    0.696364    -0.707107     0.122788
    0.696364     0.707107     0.122788
   -0.173648 -2.08167e-17     0.984808
```

It seems glog will automatically fill '0' to the empty place before number. How can I make glog output format be same with std::cout(not fill 0)?

Comment: Have you tried `LOG(INFO) << std::setfill(' ') << ...;`?

Comment: I tried but failed when compiling, error is: ‘setfill’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘fill’?, then I tried std::fill(' '), but it also doesn't work.

Comment: You need to `#include <iomanip>` to use `std::setfill`.

Comment: I tested setfill() after include<iomanip>, unfortunately, it also doesn't work: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘std::_Setfill<const char*>’)
   31 |   LOG(INFO) << "using glog, sophus_R is:\n" << std::setfill(" ") << sophus_R.matrix();
      |                                             ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                            |
      |                                                            std::_Setfill<const char*>

Comment: Please copy what I wrote exactly as I wrote it: `std::setfill(' ')` - as you can see at [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill), it takes a `char`, not a `const char*`.

Comment: It success, thanks for your patient help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `glog` stream's fill character has been set to `0`. I suggest explicitly setting it back to a space, `' '` using [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill):

```
#include <iomanip>

LOG(INFO) << "using glog, sophus_R is:\n" << std::setfill(' ') << sophus_R.matrix();
```